# Changing h1 color of Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

pretty new to Bootstrap and just started to play around with it. But there's one thing (that should be extremely obvious) that I can't get to work. And thats changing the color of the h1 tags in the jumbotron.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello WWW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Progression of Connected Computing</h1>
        <p>Learn more about the internet</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css code:

```
.jumbotron h1{
    color: #fff;
}

.jumbotron p{
    color: #fff;
}
```

The problem is, the p tags are correctly changed and turn white, but for some reason the h1 tags don't? Probably something silly I'm doing but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must include your custom `main.css` file after you are including the `bootstrap.css` one if you want to override your `bootstrap` styles with your custom `main.css` styles.

Comment: remember to name your css file as "main.css". even if you place your css line below the bootstrap call, it wont overwrite the default (e.g: if the name of your file is style.css, rename it as main.css)

Answer (score 1):

Your custom CSS file should be placed AFTER the `bootstrap.min.css`, so you are able to override it.

Like this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to do that: just wrap h1 blog inside for example span blog; then apply bootstrap for span blog. For example:

```
<span class="text-success"><h1>Hello World</h1></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to apply white color specifically (as in your example), then using Bootstrap's color utility class `.text-white` is an option:

```
<h1 class="text-white">My Text</h1>
```

For more info on other color classes, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#color